# How to calculate all MPG in a list of Fuel Entries from Realm Database

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, realm

Ok, so what I have going on is this. I have a "Car" object, with an array of "FuelEntries". Each FuelEntry has properties for mileage, gallonsPumped and a Bool value for "fillUp".

I am successfully calculating the latest fuel mileage in my app, and displaying the results using the following method:

```
    - (float)calculateMPG:(Car*)car {
    RLMResults *fuelResults1 = [car.fuelEntries objectsWhere:@"fillUp = YES"];
    if (fuelResults1.count <= 1) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        NSUInteger __block firstEntry = 0;
        NSUInteger __block secondEntry = 0;
        float __block gallonsTotal = 0.0;

        RLMResults *fuelResults = [car.fuelEntries sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"date" ascending:NO];
        NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (FuelEntry *entry in fuelResults) {
            [results addObject:entry];
        }

        [results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(FuelEntry *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if (obj.fillUp == YES && firstEntry == 0) {
                firstEntry = obj.mileage;
                gallonsTotal += obj.gallons;
            } else if (obj.fillUp == NO && firstEntry == 0) {
                idx++;
            } else if (obj.fillUp == YES && firstEntry != 0) {
                secondEntry = obj.mileage;
                *stop = YES;
            } else {
                gallonsTotal += obj.gallons;
            }

        }];

        return (firstEntry - secondEntry) / gallonsTotal;
    }
}
```

However, I am stuck on how to iterate over the whole array and calculate *all* possible MPG readings, so that I can create a report over time.

I am considering creating a RLMObject called `MPGEntry`, but if I could just calculate it whenever it was needed, I think it would be simpler.

Here is my "Car" class header:

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

#import "OilChange.h"
#import "FuelEntry.h"
#import "ServiceEntry.h"
#import "MonthlyMilesEntry.h"
#import "PhotoObject.h"
#import "MPGEntry.h"

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(OilChange)
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(FuelEntry)
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(MonthlyMilesEntry)
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(ServiceEntry)


@interface Car : RLMObject
@property NSString *uuid;
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *make;
@property NSString *VIN;
@property NSInteger year;
//@property BOOL activeCar;
@property NSInteger currentMileage;
@property NSString *driverID;
@property NSInteger oilChangeMiles;
@property NSInteger nextOilChange;


@property RLMArray<PhotoObject> *carPhoto;
@property RLMArray<OilChange> *oilChanges;
@property RLMArray<FuelEntry> *fuelEntries;
@property RLMArray<ServiceEntry> *serviceEntries;
@property RLMArray<MonthlyMilesEntry> *monthlyMilesEntries;
@property RLMArray<MPGEntry> *mpgEntries;

+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues;
+ (NSString *)primaryKey;

@end
```

And this is my current "FuelEntry" header:

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import "PhotoObject.h"

@interface FuelEntry : RLMObject

@property NSDate *date;
@property NSInteger mileage;
@property double price;
@property double gallons;
@property BOOL fillUp;
@property RLMArray<PhotoObject> *receipts;

+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues;

@end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, your logic there grabs all fuel entries tied to a car, but then uses that loop to work out the most recent 2 fill up events to work out the latest MPG.

Since you've already got all of the fuel entries, I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to iterate through the whole array to work out previous MPG results.

Hopefully, it's just a matter of creating another array object to hold the MPG results, and then whenever you reach the point in  the loop where you have both a 'firstEntry' and a 'secondEntry', you perform the calculation there, and then reset those two entries.

Let me know if I'm missing anything here!

Comment: Well, I'm not actually calculating past the second fill up. I stop there. I was trying to modify this to walk through all the code in a migration block once, for the current test version I have been using, and I don't remember what I did, but I just kept ending up with one result. I wasn't sure how to convert what I have here to something that will continue past the "last" MPG, and keep going until it goes through all the entries creating all possible MPG entries. I know I'm either going to be resetting secondEntry to firstEntry and keep enumerating, or create mpg entries as I go.

Comment: Fair enough. Yeah, in that case, I agree with the MPG entries idea. Explicitly keeping track of which fuel entry conforms to which fill up event would most likely make things a bit easier. :)

Comment: Feels like I am almost there, but I don't know. Every time I try to do it I end up going down a rabbit hole. Any idea how to turn this into something that would iterate through and store MPG entries? Maybe take a different approach altogether? I need to modify the array, but I don't think I can modify an array I am enumerating over. I need to remove entries after enumerating over them, then when I find a result, start over with what's left. At least that's what I think...

Comment: Sorry for the delay Darrell! I don't know if I can help you completely re-architect the solution, but I think you were on the right path already. Like I said before, it might be easier to simply calculate the MPG entries and save them to the Realm database instead of trying to retroactively recalculate them. Good luck! :)